# How can I tell if a repository has outgoing changes from a shell script and safely detect real errors?

Tags: mercurial, sh

```
$ hg outgoing -q
$ echo $?
1
```

It seems that Mercurial uses an exit code of `1` to indicate that there are no outgoing changesets. This makes it hard for me as a script writer to tell if there are outgoing changesets or if there is a general error. For example, if the machine is disconnected from the Internet, I want to detect the error. Consider this scenario:

```
$ hg outgoing -q
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
$ echo $?
255
```

Both return error codes. Can I rely on Mercurial to return `0` if there are outgoing changesets, `1` if there are none, and `255` if there is an actual error?

In [the documentation for `hg outgoing`](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#outgoing), the only thing I can find is:

> Returns 0 if there are outgoing changes, 1 otherwise.

I did not see any obvious discussion in the documentation about return codes in general. The docs don’t appear to talk about this return code of `255` at all.

Can I trust that `hg outgoing` will use something other than `0` and `1` in an actual case and where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases (not just `outgoing`), `hg` will return one of three exit codes:

- `0`: Success
- `1`: Could not fulfill the command (in your case, there was nothing to show)
- `255`: Catastrophic error (in your case, unreachable remote)

While `hg help scripting` might prove interesting and useful for future projects, checking if `$?` is less than 2 will probably get you what you want if your goal is simply "did not fail" (or, conversely, greater than 1 for a failure).

There are other cases when it will exit with `1` besides no outgoing changesets, but I seriously doubt you'll encounter any of them from `outgoing -q` in the scenario you seem to be implying. (And, indeed, I've rarely seen a `1` from `outgoing -q` in any other situation in the real world; the only time I can immediately think of was a scenario where it sh ould still be treated programatically as "no outgoing changesets".)

Comment: Could you point specifically to somewhere that documents the `255` return code? I don't see it under `hg help scripting`.

Comment: Unfortunately, hg's return values are underdocumented. If you look at the sources, you will see that there are many places where it emits a return value of -1. This is equivalent to 255 on most modern systems. I don't have this particular instance's exit path readily available, but it shouldn't be too hard to find. If you really need it, I'll track it down later for you. Unfortunately, it's not something that I can really put into the answer, as the source file and line number will likely change over time.